# How to obtain all the variables in an R code expression?

Tags: r

How can an expression in R be decoded to get all the variables involved?

For example if you have:

```
z<-x+y;

get_all_variables(z);

[1] 'x' 'y'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `all.vars`, but you need to quote your expression:

```
all.vars(quote(x + y))
# [1] "x" "y"
```

You can't just use `z` as you describe it contains an *evaluated* expression (i.e. the result of the expression), not the expression itself.  You can write a function that removes one step:

```
get_all_variables <- function(expr) all.vars(substitute(expr))
get_all_variables(x + y)
# [1] "x" "y"
```

But you will not be able to recover the expression from `z`, unless you create `z` by `z <- quote(x + y)` or some such.

If you have the expression in a string, then you can use @sunny's technique combined with `all.vars`:

```
all.vars(parse(text="z <- x + y"))
# [1] "z" "x" "y"
```

Though obviously you get `z` as well.  As always, don't evaluate arbitrary text with `parse` in case someone [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) you.

Comment: good advice not to `parse` blindly, as the good XKCD shows. :D :D

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know, you would need to store the expression in a string. Then you can parse it with `getParseData`:

```
txt <- "z<-x+y"

sf <- srcfile("txt")   
df = getParseData(sf)    
df$text[df$token=="SYMBOL"][2:3]
```

For further edification, here is what the result of `getParseData` looks like in its entirety:

```
   line1 col1 line2 col2 id parent       token terminal text
11     1    1     1    6 11      0        expr    FALSE     
1      1    1     1    1  1      3      SYMBOL     TRUE    z
3      1    1     1    1  3     11        expr    FALSE     
2      1    2     1    3  2     11 LEFT_ASSIGN     TRUE   <-
10     1    4     1    6 10     11        expr    FALSE     
4      1    4     1    4  4      6      SYMBOL     TRUE    x
6      1    4     1    4  6     10        expr    FALSE     
5      1    5     1    5  5     10         '+'     TRUE    +
7      1    6     1    6  7      9      SYMBOL     TRUE    y
9      1    6     1    6  9     10        expr    FALSE
```