# How to obtain all the variables that need to be defined prior evaluating an expression in R?

Tags: r

If I have an expression:

```
z <- x+y
```

`x` and `y` need to be defined whereas `z` does not. How can I obtain just `x` and `y`?

```
missing_values('z<-x+y');
[1] "x" "y"
```

`z` needs to be stripped in order to suggest to the user what values need to be defined before evaluating the expression.

Comment: How general does your desired solution need to be? The left hand side of an assignment expression in R could contain lots of complicated stuff.

Comment: Basically I need any variables needed so R throws no erros

Comment: are you looking for a general solution that works for any R expression? or just a simple case like this

Comment: How is this question different from [the one you asked earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361019/how-to-obtain-all-the-variables-in-an-r-code-expression)?

Comment: @RichardScriven Maybe the difference is that they want to find those not already defined, like `setdiff(all.vars(quote(x+y)), ls())` ?

Comment: @Frank No because he doesn't want one that will be assigned by evaluating the expression

Comment: @SeñorO Subset it out, as the first var appearing? `setdiff(all.vars(quote(z <- x+y))[-1], ls())` If they want to mix assignments with other things, or to assign strangely like `x <- x+y`, then something fancier/uglier might be needed.

Comment: @Frank unless it uses `->`. In any case I think this is kinda useless. If you're playing a game of define variables until you're not getting an error you're not using R correctly.

Comment: @Frank, ja ja. I am creating an app based on r. And I need this information. Actually I am looking for the very general solution. Because when users input their expression they could be adding anything.

Comment: this sounds like a design flaw, what if you encounter things like `res <- eval(parse(text="a<-b+c"))`, just to mention one, but there are plenty of strange cases

Comment: @nongkrong ...or what about `res <- eval(parse(text = "res <- eval(parse(text = 'a <- b + c'))"))` ;)

Comment: @joran did you mean https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=recursion :D

Comment: Maybe it is very difficult to parse such a thing right?

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking".  Please edit your question to give more details, and examples such as those in the comments below that may clarify what you mean.  Are you interested in the left-hand side at all?  Do you need to know whether variables are defined in the workspace already (see `ls()`, as in @Frank's comment above) ? etc.

Comment: @BenBolker I think he just wants whatever symbols would be declared missing if the expression were evaluated.  Joran appears to agree.

Comment: @BrodieG That's my hunch, but I'm sympathetic to others finding it unclear

Comment: Can you clarify *why* you need this? Maybe you don't really need all this trouble and there's a much simpler solution to your *real* problem.

Comment: I really don't think I should spend any more time on this until it's clarified/expanded, but: another way to tackle this would be to wrap it in a `tryCatch()` and figure out what R complains about.  The problem would be that it would only find out about the *first* problem, but maybe there's a way around that ...

Comment: @awavi, your gist appears to suggest my answer gets to what you want.  Is that the case?  As you can see there some confusion on this thread about what you actually want.

Comment: @BrodieG thanks, based on some testing I have done it looks pretty good. I am now trying to implement it on openCPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that assumes multi argument functions evaluate their arguments left to right.  This is true of the typical binary operators, which is what you seem interested in, but as I noted in my comment to @BenBolker's answer, is not universally true.

```
find_unbound <- function(lang) {
  stopifnot(is.language(lang), !is.expression(lang))

  bound <- character()
  unbound <- character()

  rec_fun <- function(lang) {
    if(is.call(lang)) {
      # These are assignment calls; if any symbols are assigned and have
      # not already been found in a leaf, they are defined as bound

      if((lang[[1]] == as.name("<-") || lang[[1]] == as.name("="))) {
        for(i in as.list(lang)[-(1:2)]) Recall(i)
        if(is.name(lang[[2]]) && !as.character(lang[[2]]) %in% unbound)
          bound <<- c(bound, as.character(lang[[2]]))
      } else for(i in as.list(lang)[-1]) Recall(i)                
    } else if (is.name(lang) && ! as.character(lang) %in% bound)
      # this is a leaf; any previously bound symbols are by definition
      # unbound

      unbound <<- c(unbound, as.character(lang))
  }
  rec_fun(lang)
  unique(unbound)
}
```

`find_unbound` recurses all the way down to the leaves of the expressions to determine whether each symbol has been bound or not.  Here are some tests to illustrate:

```
find_unbound(quote(z <- x + y))
# [1] "x" "y"
find_unbound(quote(z <- x + (y <- 3)))
# [1] "x"
find_unbound(quote(z <- z + 1))           # we even figure out `z` depends on itself, so must be provided
# [1] "z"
find_unbound(quote(z <- x + (x <- 3)))    # note `x` is evaluated before `x <- 3`
# [1] "x"
find_unbound(quote(z <- (x <- 3) + x))    # but here `x <- 3` is evaluated before `x`
# character(0)
find_unbound(quote({x <- 3; z <- x + y})) # works with multiple calls
# [1] "y"
find_unbound(quote({z <- x + y; x <- 3})) # order matters, just like in R evaluation
# [1] "x" "y"
```

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you are asking how you can ignore the left-hand side of the expression.

```
txt <- "z <- x+y"
p <- parse(text=txt)
```

For reasons I don't understand R returns `expression(z <- x+y)` -- we need to strip the "expression" part first:

```
p2 <- p[[1]]
```

Then we can get the variables from the right-hand side:

```
all.vars(p2[[3]])
## [1] "x" "y"
```

As long as you don't **evaluate** the parsed text, I think you should be safe from users entering stuff like this:

```
txt <- "z <- system('rm -Rf *')"
```

...

I think both sides can get pretty complicated and this will still work, because the `<-` operator has fairly low precedence:

```
txt <- "names(x)[1] <- as.character(a * log(x))"
all.vars(parse(text=txt)[[1]][[3]])
## [1] "a" "x"
```

Comment: Will this handle situations where the left hand side involves an indexing expression that needs to be evaluated? e.g. a `[<-` assignment?

Comment: I will be using opencpu so I think dangerous functions like system are disabled.

Comment: @BenBolker I don't understand why it's not expected that `parse` will return an expression object? That's what its help page says it does.

Comment: @joran: `txt <- "z[1] <- x+y"; p <- parse(text=txt); all.vars(p[[1]][[3]]); #[1] "x" "y"`

Comment: @BondedDust it is expected; it's just frustrating (to me) that I have to use `[[1]]` to strip down to what I actually want.

Comment: @joran: can you show what you have in mind (i.e. anything other than BondedDusts's example)?  As long as the operator precedence is OK I think `[[3]]` should successfully pull out the RHS ...

Comment: What about if you have something like x=0; z<-x+y? Then only 'y' is needed

Comment: @BenBolker: It's just a list. If you want the value of the first element , rather than the sublist, you need "[[".

Comment: My thought was based on my understanding of the intent of the question, which was that they wanted every variable that may need to be evaluated regardless of which side of the assignment it falls on. So where you're doing a subassignment where the indices come from another expression with variables.

Comment: Now we're guessing and should wait for the OP to clarify.  (Maybe I should have waited too.)

Comment: You can use this as a test:  `identical(eval(p[[1]][[1]]),  `<-`)
[1] TRUE`    Where the backticks that I cannot put into the comment get put back in.

Comment: Ok. I am developing a site to have a community where people can createm calculators without having to develop anything but the math of it. So I want to add r code and guess which inputs will need to be filled to get a result. For that reason I want this information. Maybe that helps better to understand what I need to achieve.

Comment: @awavi, if you're willing to disallow things such as `f(x <- 3, x)` then it should be possible to do this.  The problem with the above expression is that which of the two arguments gets evaluated first is a function of the code inside `f`, which would be really annoying to try to parse and interpret to figure out whether the user needs to specify the second `x`.

Comment: @BrodieG this is a good point. However, I will only put inputs that will be translated into something like x <- 2; or x<-[1,2,3]; before the actual code. So I guess it will be up to the calc developer to actually know that and try to work it around from that point.