# Determine the Variables in an Expression

Tags: r

I'd be much obliged if somebody could let me know if there's a way to get the variables in a string.
E.g. `"x + y" -> c( "x", "y" )`, `"x * y + z" -> c( "x", "y", "z" )` and so on. Any help appreciated.

Just FWIW, it's easy to do this with some string parsing, but I want to re-use an existing solution (as opposed to having to define another solution).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain all the variables in an R code expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361019/how-to-obtain-all-the-variables-in-an-r-code-expression)

Comment: @digEmAll Thanks. It's a duplicate.